# can i move the extended pertition and resize the ext4 partition to the rest of the disk

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, external-hdd

i have cloned my 60 GB hard drive to a 640 GB but i can't resize the ext4 partition because the extended partition is in the way, so i would like to know if i can move it without braking something and how to move it?? 
her is my partition

[image]

i am running Ubuntu 14.04 desktop on a Lenovo G500 laptop

i have lookit in gparted but coundt finde out how to move a partition
i have tried to google it put could't find it, so i desidet to ask here

Answer (score 1):

You can only merge partitions that are next to each other.

If you want to ditch the extended partition you also will need to ditch the swap partition. That will remove the extended partition. And only after `sda5` is gone you will be able to merge the unallocated with the primary.

This will result in 1 big disk, and you will need to recreate the swap file with the [mkswap](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man8/mkswap.8.html).